# Question about relation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

Making a line of numbers 1-10 I wrote corresponding cube values under them. Taking the difference of the differences I arrived at this. Where has the 6 come from? It always results in 6 times the value of $x$?

$$((x+1)^3-x^3))-(x^3-(x-1)^3)=6(x)$$

**EDIT FOR RELEVANCE**

When I wrote a number line for prime gaps, I found a similarity in the pattern to the coefficient of $x$ which related directly to $P_2^2-P_1^2$ where $P_2$ is equal to the next prime $>P_1$.

$G = primegap$

If $G = 1$ then $x = 4x$.

If $G = 2$, then $x= 8x$

If $G = 3$, then $x= 12x$

...

and so on and so forth. This series only holds up to the 'centre' digit of $P_1$ and $P_2$. In example: $$11^2-7^2 = 8(9)$$ $$9=7+2$$  $$9=11-2$$

or

$$79^2-73^2 = 12(76)$$ $$76 = 73+3$$ $$76 = 79-3$$

Comment: Do you know the general formula for $(a+b)^3$?

Comment: Try expanding the cubes, you'll see where the $6$ comes from.

Comment: You did not actually write **cube roots** of the numbers $1$ to $10$, did you? I think you mean to say you wrote the **cubes** of the numbers. The **cube root** of $10,$ for example, is about $2.1544.$

Comment: @Barb: I think you mean that you "wrote corresponding cube values" not "cube *root* values". That said ... Congratulations! You have discovered an interesting property of consecutive cubes. If you experiment with other powers (or even polynomials), you may well notice an interesting pattern in those final numbers. BTW, the term of art for the process involved here is "finite differences".

Comment: Thanks for the terminology, I have changed it. I notice that the left side of the equation is a derivative and the right-hand side integration. What is the best way to represent each side on a graph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you familiar with the formula used to expand a cubed term? $$(x+y)^3$$
In case you are not, here is a quick overview
$$(x+y)^3$$
$$=(x+y)(x+y)(x+y)$$
$$=((x+y)(x+y))(x+y)$$
$$(x^2 + yx + yx + y^2)(x+y)$$
$$(x^2 + 2yx + y^2)(x+y)$$
$$x^3 + 2x^2y + y^2x + yx^2 +2y^2x +y^3$$
$$=x^3 +3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3$$
The negative case is very similar, you should get
$$(x-y)^3 = x^3 - 3x^2y + 3xy^2 -y^3$$
And for the solution:
$$((x+1)^3-x^3)-(x^3-(x-1)^3)$$
$$= (x^3+3x^2+3x+1)-x^3)-(x^3-(x^3-3x^2+3x -1))$$
$$= 3x^2 + 3x + 1 -(3x^2 -3x +1)$$
$$ = 6x $$
Hence, solved.

Comment: this is great. Thank you for the explanation

Comment: Glad i helped:)